# Как в PyQt5 сохранить положение Dial ручки после закрытия программы?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qsettings, qdial

В данном коде я освоил сохранение значения `checkBox` в **.ini** файл при нажатии кнопки "**`Выход`**".

Что нужно дописать в коде, чтоб сохранилось положение регулятора `Dial`?

***main.py***

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.Qt import QSettings
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config.ini'


class New(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()

        loadUi("checkBox_Dial_save.ui", self)
        self.load_settings()
        self.Exit.clicked.connect(self.ExitClicked)

        self.dial.setMinimum(0)
        self.dial.setMaximum(10)
        self.dial.setValue(5)

    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue('BoolValue', int(self.cb_flag.isChecked()))

    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        self.cb_flag.setChecked(bool(int(settings.value('BoolValue', 0))))

    def ExitClicked(self):
        self.save_settings()
        sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***checkBox_Dial_save.ui***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>600</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="maximumSize">
    <size>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>600</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>761</width>
      <height>95</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string>GroupBox</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QDial" name="dial">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>100</x>
       <y>28</y>
       <width>100</width>
       <height>55</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="wrapping">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="notchesVisible">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QCheckBox" name="cb_flag">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>12</x>
       <y>63</y>
       <width>81</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>CheckBox</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="Exit">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>650</x>
       <y>30</y>
       <width>93</width>
       <height>28</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Выход</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Практический тоже самое что вы делали для `checkBox`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.Qt import QSettings
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config.ini'


class New(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()

        loadUi("checkBox_Dial_save.ui", self)
        
#        self.Exit.clicked.connect(self.ExitClicked)
        self.Exit.clicked.connect(self.close)                           # +++
        
        self.dial.setMinimum(0)
        self.dial.setMaximum(10)
        self.dial.setValue(5)        

        self.load_settings() # <---- !!!  это последнее что вы делвете в конструкторе 

#        self.dial.setMinimum(0)
#        self.dial.setMaximum(10)
#        self.dial.setValue(5)

    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue('BoolValue', int(self.cb_flag.isChecked()))
        
        settings.setValue('DialValue', self.dial.value())                 # +++

    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        self.cb_flag.setChecked(bool(int(settings.value('BoolValue', 0))))
        
        self.dial.setValue(int(settings.value('DialValue', 0)))           # +++
        

#    def ExitClicked(self):
#        self.save_settings()
#        sys.exit()
        
    def closeEvent(self, event):                                     # +++
        self.save_settings()                                         # +++


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]